# Loop through two tables in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Let's say I have two tables. Table 1 is called "rooms" and table 2 is called "fruits". In every room there is a left and a right side and the fruits from table "fruits" are going to be put to the left or right side of the room.

An example:
In room "kitchen" we have 2 bananas on the right side and 5 bananas on the left side.

My tables according the example:

## room

id     name

1      kitchen

2      bedroom

## fruits

id | name | 1_right | 1_left | 2_right | 2_left

1 | apple | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0

2 | banana | 2 | 5 | 0 | 0

As you can see "1_right" is "kitchenID_right". In the blade view I would like to loop through my "rooms" with the data from "right" and "left":

Where are bananas?

- kitchen right: 2
- kitchen left: 5
- bedroom right: 0
- bedroom left: 0

Any ideas on how I can do this with Laravel? Of course, I can do a sql query in the blade view, but since I know that this is bad practice I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to achieve the same result.

Comment: You can make relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your rooms are fixed, you don't need to create rooms table. Otherwise it's not a good idea to add IDs of room table as field prefix in fruits table. You can not join them in a proper way. You should alter your tables.
You can create a 3rd -mapping- table.

e.g.

```
room_fruits [table name]
room_id
left_fruit_id
right_fruit_id
```

You should also use [many to many relationship of Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Comment: Thank you, Koray! I was hoping to achieve the same result without a pivot table since the rooms are fixed.

Answer (score 1):

First you should re-structure your database as this ..

**ROOMS**

```
id , name
```

** FRUITS **

```
id , name , left_qty , right_qty , room_id
```

Then in your **MODEL ROOM**

```
public function fruits()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Fruit');
}
```

in your **MODEL FRUITS**

```
public function room()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Room');
}
```

so in controller you can do

```
$rooms = Room::all();
foreach($rooms as $room)
{
    echo $room->name;
    foreach($room->fruits as $fruit)
    {
        echo $fruit->name . ': (right)' . $fruit->right_qty . ' (left)' . $fruit->left_qty;
    }
}
```

[REFERENCE](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Thank you, Demonyowh! My "fruits" table is quite large and I was trying to get around multiple "same fruit"-rows.

Answer (score 0):

Just a slight improvisation of what @Koray Küpe said, you can create the mapping table as follows, but keeping the rooms table as it is (since rooms may not always be fixed):

```
Table: room_fruits
-------------------
id
room_id (from rooms table)
fruit_id (from fruits table)
left (boolean)
right (boolean)
```

This way it'll be easier for you to select fruits that are only on either left or right room when building your query

Comment: Thank you, BangularTK! I preferred your solution before trying to get around the pivot table. The only difference is that "left" and "right" is not boolean since I can store the amount of fruits directly in those fields.